# Emit style value to parent on vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, eventemitter

I am fairly new to VueJS and trying to figure everything out.

I have a specific issue on my site where I have a TopBar component that contains the logo and the menu.

```
<template>
  <div id="topBar">
    <div class="container align-center justify-between">
      <router-link to="/">
        <img src="@/assets/logo-white.svg" alt="logo" />
      </router-link>
      <a href="#" @click="showMenu = !showMenu" class="menu-button">
        <img src="@/assets/menu-icon.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav id="menu" class="flex align-center" v-bind:class="{ 'js-active': showMenu }">
      <ul id="topNav" class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
        </li>

        <li>
          <router-link to="/opret">Register</router-link>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="close-button" @click="showMenu = false">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 33 33" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M2.76316 30.2368L30.4059 2.59409" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square" />
              <path d="M30.2368 30.2368L2.59409 2.59409" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square" />
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="container">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <router-link to="/register">Register</router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link to="/news">News</router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link to="/about>About</router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CloseMixin from "../mixins/close";

export default {
  mixins: [CloseMixin],
  data: function() {
    return {
      showMenu: false
    };
  },
  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.showMenu = false;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      let nav = document.querySelector("#menu");

      if (nav.classList.contains("js-active")) {
        nav.classList.remove("js-active");
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {}
};
</script>
```

And I am inserting this component in my App.vue view

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <TopBar></TopBar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

My issue is that on some of my views the logo and colors has to be dark, because the view has a light background. So I somehow want to `$emit` a menuStyle to my TopBar parent component so that I can set a logo and color based on the menuStyle emitted from the child

So that I might end up with something like

```
<div id="topBar">
   <router-link to="/">
        <img src="@/assets/logo-dark.svg" alt="logo" v-if="menuStyle === 'dark' />
        <img src="@/assets/logo-white.svg" alt="logo" v-else />
     </router-link>
</div>
```

My main child view is this:

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Profile",
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit the event from child router view to outer component, here is the trick

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <TopBar :menuStyle="menuStyleProp"></TopBar>
    <router-view @eventFromChild="updateMenuStyle"></router-view>
    <Footer></Fdooter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export.default {
name: 'main-component',
data() {
 return {
   menuStyleProp: "",
 };
},
methods: {
  updateMenuStyle(val) {
    this.menuStyleProp = val;
  }
}
}
</script>

F
```

rom the child you can just emit the event, so that router view listen to that event and update the props, top bar get updated with the new svg

> In topbar component

```
<div id="topBar">
   <router-link to="/">
        <img src="@/assets/logo-dark.svg" alt="logo" v-if="menuStyle === 'dark' />
        <img src="@/assets/logo-white.svg" alt="logo" v-else />
     </router-link>
</div>

<script>
export default {
name: 'topbar-component',
props: {
  menuStyle: {
    type: String,
    default: "dark",
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

> In the child component trigger an event to router view via

```
this.$router.app.$emit("eventFromChild", "dark") // change the value to dark or any
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I am not quite sure how to trigger it on my child view - Profile

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to trigger the event ?

Comment: Yes I did.

It is this part I am in doubt about 

"this.$router.app.$emit("eventFromChild", "dark")"

Comment: Yes if you want to trigger an event programmatically from a component to parent component you can use this.$emit(“yourEventName”, “value pass to parent”), if you want to trigger event which is in router view from child , then you have to do like this , this.$router.app.$emit(“event from child”, value).

Comment: Yeah... So far so good. But I am unsure where in my code on Profile.vue I have to trigger the event. 

I have tried to place it both in "methods" and "created" and in <router-view> on profile.vue but it doesn't work, so obviously I am doing it wrong :)

Comment: Have you added event in @eventFromChild in router view?

Comment: Yeah.. I have that in App.vue where TopBar component is being included exactly as shown in your solution

Comment: Okie I’ll try to create a small vue app and add this code and share to you

Comment: I've created a small prototype , let me know when you are free..

Comment: Let me see it :)